# JupyterLab nvdashboard failed to install in Jupyter >= 3.0 with react >= 17.0.0

Tags: reactjs, gpu, nvidia, jupyter-lab, conda-forge

I would like to use the [jupyterlab-nvdashboard](https://github.com/rapidsai/jupyterlab-nvdashboard) to monitor the GPU performance from JupyterLab. Although it is not mentioned in the github, I found the extension is also available in the conda-forge channel and I installed it from there.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-nvdashboard
```

The installation went without errors and the last environment list entry shows that jupyterlab-nvdashboard-0.6.0 was installed together with the dependency pynvml-11.0.0:

```
2021-10-21 12:15:21  (rev 8)
    +jupyterlab-nvdashboard-0.6.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pynvml-11.0.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
```

I am running a recent version of jupyter-lab >= 3.0

```
$ jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.28.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.1
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 7.0.6
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : 1.11.1
jupyterlab       : 3.1.18
```

This is the error I am getting when I tried to install the labextension.

```
$ jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-nvdashboard
An error occurred.
ValueError: The extension "jupyterlab-nvdashboard" does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.


Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension        Package
>=3.1.17 <3.2.0         >=2.0.0 <3.0.0   @jupyterlab/application
>=3.1.17 <3.2.0         >=2.0.0 <3.0.0   @jupyterlab/apputils
>=5.1.17 <5.2.0         >=4.0.0 <5.0.0   @jupyterlab/coreutils
>=17.0.1 <18.0.0        >=16.4.2 <17.0.0 react
>=17.0.1 <18.0.0        >=16.9.0 <17.0.0 react-dom
```

And this is the output of the server extension list command:

```
$ jupyter server extension list
Config dir: /home/<username>/.jupyter

Config dir: /home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/test/etc/jupyter
    dask_labextension enabled
    - Validating dask_labextension...
      dask_labextension 5.1.0 OK
    jupyter_server_proxy enabled
    - Validating jupyter_server_proxy...
      jupyter_server_proxy  OK
    jupyterlab enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab...
      jupyterlab 3.1.18 OK
    jupyterlab_nvdashboard enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab_nvdashboard...
       X validation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the dashboard works inside JupyterLab despite **jupyter labextension** telling me the X validation failed. So all good. =) [image: GPU Dashboard in JupyterLab]